# How to patch Solaris

Tags: solaris, patch-management

I have Solaris 10 and 11 running on my system. I want to update all of them to newest patch.
I don't have license or support plan for Solaris yet (the OS is pre-installed on my server). 
On Solaris 11 I heard I need a support license and a cert to connect to Oracle software repository. What about Solaris 10? Can I fetch patch bundle and install it without connect to Oracle (for both Solaris 10 and 11)?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a support license to be able to use support.oracle.com and download the patch bundle.